# Zoom to extent using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, attributeerror

Working on being able to zoom to the extent of features in a search row to produce individual maps for row (like data driven pages but for individual rows on the dataset).

I just can't seem to get it to zoom to extent?  I have looked around but can't find what I need in the syntax help guide.

Script below

```
import arcpy


from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
#Set File workspace
file_workspace = 'N:\\GIS\\Projects\\AA_Leith_Hawkins_TestBed\\Search_Cursor\\Search_Cursor.gdb'
env.workspace = file_workspace

#buffer set up
Holdings = 'N:\GIS\Projects\AA_Leith_Hawkins_TestBed\Search_Cursor\Search_Cursor.gdb\Data\Holdings'
distances = [1000, 4000]
unit = "Meters"
#Make a feature layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Holdings,'Holdings_Layer')

#searchcursor for evey row in dataset
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Holdings, ['Holding_Reference_Number'])as Holdings_Ref_cursor:
    for row in Holdings_Ref_cursor:
    print row[0]
    query = "Holding_Reference_Number = " + str(row[0])
    print query
    File_output = file_workspace+ '\\' 'Buffer_'+str(row[0])
    #print File_output

    #Select Feature using the reference number from holdings layer
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('Holdings_Layer', 'NEW_SELECTION',"Holding_Reference_Number = " + str(row[0]))

    # Export holding to geodatabase
    Holding_Boundary = file_workspace+ '\\' 'Holding_'+str(row[0])
    arcpy.management.CopyFeatures('Holdings_Layer', Holding_Boundary)

    #Mutliple ring Buffer using Selected Features
    arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis('Holdings_Layer', File_output, distances, unit, "", "ALL")
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(File_output, 'Buffer_Layer')
   #arcpy.Buffer_analysis("Holdings_Layer", ofc, var_Buffer, "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL", "")
    print 'Buffer complete'

    #Intersect Features
    Intersect_out_feaatures = file_workspace+ '\\' 'Intersect_'+str(row[0])
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis([Holdings,File_output],Intersect_out_feaatures, "", "", "INPUT")
    print "intersect Complete"

    #add Layers to the Map
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('N:\\GIS\Projects\\AA_Leith_Hawkins_TestBed\\Search_Cursor\\Search_Cursor_mxd.mxd')
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(File_output)
    addLayer2 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(Holding_Boundary)
    addLayer3 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(Intersect_out_feaatures)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "TOP")
    print addLayer
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer2, "TOP")
    print addLayer2
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer3, "TOP")
    print addLayer3

    #zoom to layer

    print df
    lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df)[2].name
    print lyr
    extent = lyr.getExtent()
    print extent
    df.extent = extent

    #Export Map to PNG File
    Png_output = "N:\\GIS\Projects\\AA_Leith_Hawkins_TestBed\\" + str(row[0]) + '.png'
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd,Png_output)
    print 'Map Created'
    del mxd
```

The error message I get is (I have included the prints from the run as well so you can see what they produce to try and make it easier:

```
108050022
Holding_Reference_Number = 108050022
Buffer complete
intersect Complete
Buffer_108050022
Holding_108050022
Intersect_108050022
<geoprocessing Data Frame object object at 0x1262EC00>
Buffer_108050022
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\GIS\Projects\AA_Leith_Hawkins_TestBed\Search_Cursor\Script\SearchCUrsor.py", line 65, in <module>
extent = lyr.getExtent()
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'getExtent'
```

Comment: Please trim your code down to a test snippet that reproduces your error and replace your code via an [edit] to your question.  See [Writing code snippets to get quicker answers?](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error indicates that your `lyr` variable is a `unicode` object (not a `Layer` object).  This is due to you setting your `lyr` with `.name` (your variable is just storing the name, not reference to the actual layer.

```
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df)[2].name
```

Remove the `.name` here and add it into the `print` line

```
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df)[2]
print lyr.name
extent = lyr.getExtent()
print extent
df.extent = extent
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE for arcpy in Arcgis Pro**:

**mapping** sub module is no longer available. Use **mp** sub module instead.

```
# read the layer information from the project and map
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("current")
mp = aprx.listMaps("Map_name")[0]    
lyr = mp.listLayers("Layer_name")[0]

# read the layout and map frame information, and update extent
lyt = p.listLayouts()[0]
mf = lyt.listElements()[2]
ext = mf.getLayerExtent(lyr, False, True)
mf.camera.setExtent(ext)
```

Note: This makes the changes in the Layout view not the Map. More information on migrating from mapping to mp can be found here: [Migrating from arcpy.mapping to ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/migratingfrom10xarcpymapping.htm)